# Check if password is valid in Keycloak from Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, passwords, keycloak

My user is already loggedin with a valid token, but in some important operations (like confirm or cancel of a paid subscription), I want it to send the password along the other data, so the server validate it.
By now, my application has the users in a database, and it was easy to develop this way.

How can I check that user sent password correctly? Will I need to try to login with the username and password in my backend?

Comment: The JIRA issue for this is https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-943. The only alternative I'm aware of is writing an SPI.

Comment: It was fixed for 4.0.0 according to the KEYCLOAK-943 issue, does it work already ?

Answer (score -1):

Your backend should already be setup as a Keycloak Client so that it can pass tokens for validation / introspection.

If you enable "Direct Access Grants" it will allow the backend to directly pass and verify username and password credentials with Keycloak.